# Mysql select from one table by options from other

Tags: mysql, select, join, filter

F.E. I have 2 tables:

Products (id,description,price)
Specifications (id_product, id_specif, specif_val)

I need to select all products wich have multiple needed specification values.
F.E. select all products which have id_specif=153 and a value for this specif_val="test1" and id_specif=55 and a value for it specif_val="test2"

Updated with my select statement, but it may be totally wrong, because I think I'm a fool yet:)

select product.id, product.brand, product.model from product left join  specif_val on product.id=specif_val.id_product where (product.id_group=5 and product.active = 1) and (specif_val.specif_val='test_val1' and specif_val.id_specif=163) and (specif_val.specif_val='test_val2' and specif_val.id_specif=155);

It shows what I need but also shows the products which have only one of needed options.

Comment: Can you show an example and the query you have tried?

Comment: tester3 - Please try write out the SQL select statement you have tried so far. SO users are more likely to help if they see your initial efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you provide table structure.
But anyway, my fixes can be helpful.

```
select product.id, product.brand, product.model 
from product 
    inner join specif_val as s1 
        on product.id=s1.id_product and s1.specif_val='test_val1' 
            and s1.id_specif=163
    inner join specif_val as s2 
        on product.id=s2.id_product and 
            s2.specif_val='test_val2' and s2.id_specif=155
where product.id_group=5 and product.active = 1;
```

For each new specification you will need to add one more

```
inner join specif_val as s2 
        on product.id=s2.id_product and 
            s2.specif_val='test_val2' and s2.id_specif=155
```

For good performance product.id and specif_val.id_product columns must be INDEXED.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FRM products p JOIN Specifications s ON p.id = s.id_product that will return all products that have data in specifications table`

To remove duplicates for products use   GROUP BY p.id